# Is it possible for a linear system to have infinitely many solutions without the augmented matrix having a row of zeroes?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

Is it possible for an augmented matrix of a  $4 \times 4$ system to have infinitely many solutions without having a row of zeroes? I think it's not but not too sure.

Comment: To have infinite solutions you would need linearly dependant rows, which means in the reduced form it would become a row of zeros

Comment: ok so its not possible without a row of zeroes right

Comment: Try a proof by contradiction, assume it is possible and show that it leads to something that cannot be possible. That will help formalise your intuition

Answer (score 0):

To be more precise, consider the system $Ax=b$ where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{4 \times 4}$ consists of all ones and $b\in \mathbb{R}^{4 \times 1}$ consists of all ones as well. In that case, we have infinite number of solutions though there is no zero rows.

However, if the augmented matrix that you intended to ask is already in REF form, then without zero rows, every column is a pivot column and there is no free variable. Hence the solution is unique.